# getting twitter's description/title from a given URL

Tags: twitter

Im a self teaching guy whos is looking to learn cibersecurity stuff; I have a lot of twitter URL among others links, but google sheets appears never to bring any info related to twitter URL title or description; however non twitter related URL are fully obtained all title and description URLs.

I have already tried all combinations for IMPORTXML including “//h1/text()“, “//meta[@name=’keywords’]/@content” and so many other but keep not working on twitter URL.
Having this twitter url for example https://twitter.com/_bin_Ash/status/1619756759345930240 IMPORTXML technically should bring first four lines from twitter URL...

Anyone have tried this before or is something propietary stuff from Twitter?

Thank you all for reading this and have a great weekend ahead!